# How can I get the ID of a still not created database Item

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

**Currently working code:** The first connection query adds a new user to the database using the information filled in the form, the second one inside the for loop checks the database if the interest already exists with the given name before it creates a new one. The missing part is the important one.

**Problem:** How can I link the new interest added to the database or an existent one if neither the user nor interest is created. I do understand that I need to run the two query below before I link them to make sure they exist, but how can I get the ID for the new user or the new interest? This all happens on the post request for a registration form.

```
connection.query('INSERT INTO User set ? ', [newUserData], function (err) {
    if (err) { throw err; }
    res.redirect('/');
});

let interests = {
    userInterests: req.body.signupNewTagInterests.split(",")
}
for (let i = 0; i < interests.userInterests.length; i++) {
    connection.query('SELECT title FROM Interest WHERE title =?', [interests.userInterests[i]], function (err, results) {
        if (err) { throw err; }
        if (typeof results[0] === 'undefined') {
            connection.query('INSERT INTO Interest (title) Value(?) ', [interests.userInterests[i]], function (err) {
                if (err) { throw err; }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

**Tabels:** 
User: 
ID
first_name
etc...

Interest: 
ID
title

User_Interests: 
User_ID
Interest_ID

Comment: probably the idea is query your tables, get the last return id, increment by one and there you go, you get the ID?

Comment: Well yes but what if multiple people are creating there account? Won't this be buggy? What if I get someone else ID because he was 0.1s faster?

Comment: That will be true any way you implement this, why do you need to know id before it's created vs right after/as it's created?

Comment: To be honest if the last query happens after the creation part it won't be a problem right? I mean the user will already exists but extremely fast.

Comment: You have to execute everything in a single `transaction` just create a storeprocedure/function in the db with all the steps.

Comment: Juan is right, but by looking at your code, user already existed before interest does, so you can get the USER id but not the interest IDs.

Comment: @Roljhon What if I insert the query after the if statement that creates the interest inside the loop.

Comment: @ajax333221 do you mean the user or interest?

Comment: @VeraPerrone I'm completely confused, how are you creating your user? how are you adding the user's interest? is it after the user is created? just think that if a user is created right before the interest, then technically you can pull that user's ID. Not really getting what you're trying to do, can't suggest anything if don't really understand you, please update your post if you have anything to add on

Comment: @Roljhon Ok so I have a registration form where users can fill in some information like name, age, email, password etc. One of the fields is a interest text field, where users can pass multiple interests separated my a ",". If the interest does not exist in the database I just add it. After that I want to link the new user and his new list of new or existing interest in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to insert the user irrespective of where interest with interest id present or not.

Then you need to insert interest into interest table if not present

Once above part is completed then you can link these two things with interest title and then insert new records in user interest table.

vice versa for interest.

Comment: So I should just add a new query after the if statement that checks for existence so I can link them? At that point both the interest and user are created.

Comment: yeah you just need to check whether that user present or not, and then interest also in the same way, once these two things done then you can link them by joining with interest

Comment: first concentrate more on inserting user and interest in their respective tables once these done sucessfully then insert link data in user interest table with additional information also

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get an id as it's entered you can use the following query:

```
 SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

or via having your framework/MySQL library (in whatever language) call

```
mysql_insert_id()
```

right after a query. You can then use that as your user_id checking in the interests database.